# Date on a cell and compare it to current date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Compare a date on cell vs current date, lets say on A1 and B1 having a date format `DD/MM/YYYY` and comparing it for today's date,

If the date on `A1` is less than or equal to date today and is less than or equal to the date on `B1` then it will call a sub.

The only thing I do care about is how to compare those on cell and the current date.

For example I made the cell look like this
`C1` cell, has value `2021` then `A1` has a formula or format I made look like this: `="2/21/"&C1` (this also includes with `B1`) (just for flexibility of years to come).

Comment: `="2/21/"&C1` does not return a date but a text string that looks like a date. you should use: `=DATE(C1,2,21)` so it returns an actual date.

Comment: ahh alright, thanks,